# How to get a single SQLite row data with its id?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-alertdialog

I have successfully retrieved SQLite data to ListView. Now I am trying to implement  OnItemClickListener to show the data in Dialog but I am getting this error

```
2019-04-08 18:42:53.020 20591-20591/com.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app, PID: 20591
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:292)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
        at com.app.SQLiteAdaptor.GetUserByUserId(SQLiteAdaptor.java:99)
        at com.app.OrderHistory$1.onItemClick(OrderHistory.java:64)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1181)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3165)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6634)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

This is where I need to retrieve row

```
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                final Dialog fullscreenDialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Dialog);
                    fullscreenDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_oh);


                SQLiteAdaptor db = new SQLiteAdaptor(c);
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = db.GetUserByUserId(i); //Line 64
                HashMap<String, String> hashDetails = userList.get(0);

                     //Use this index accordingly
                    tvit.setText(hashDetails.get("item"));
                    tvpr.setText(hashDetails.get("price"));
                    tvqu.setText(hashDetails.get("quantity"));
                    tvad.setText(hashDetails.get("address"));
                    tvna.setText(hashDetails.get("name"));
                    tvem.setText(hashDetails.get("email"));
                    tvtim.setText(hashDetails.get("time"));

fullscreenDialog.show();
}
});
```

Here is the SQLiteAdaptor get row data by id method  snippet

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUserByUserId(int userid ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); \\Line 99
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        String  query = "SELECT item, price, quantity, name, address, email, orderid FROM "+ Table_Name;

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_Name, new String[]{COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6, COL_7, COL_8, COL_9}, COL_1+ "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)},null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("item",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));
            user.put("price",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
            user.put("quantity",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_4)));
            user.put("name",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_5)));
            user.put("address",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_6)));
            user.put("email",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_7)));
            user.put("orderid",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_8)));
            user.put("time",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_9)));
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return  userList;
    }
```

And it is not null pointer exception because I am nit getting any error while retrieving data in Listview

Or any other way to how to retrieve row with its id

Any help and solutions are appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: the context in custom SQLiteOpenHelper is null

Comment: @fancyjyl how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SQLiteAdaptor db = new SQLiteAdaptor(view.getContext());
```